# My class D amp not working?

Tags: microcontroller, mosfet, amplifier, audio

I'am trying to make class D amp from GreatScott youtube channel but it doesn't work. When I connect the headphone jack and play some music to test it, the speaker starts vibrating, the hight side MOSFET gets so hot, and no sound produced. I redesign the circuit multiple times but nothing changed. The schematic is show below.

PS: Don't care about the wiring of the headphone jack female socket because I didn't use it, also  I used power regulators both for 5 and 12 V with capacitors of 47 uF to make sure it's stable.

[image]

This is another image of the circuit from GreatScott channel:
[image]

Comment: The regulator hasn't got supply de-couplers and it uses an LM386 as a preamplifier without a proper Zobel network (just an output capacitor to GND). In fact I don't see any supply de-couplers. The circuit is really poor. I dread to think what your printed circuit board layout looks like. Sorry if I'm coming over as rude but the circuit is bad. Maybe you should post images of your circuit board so we can sort this out. Ouch <-- I've just seen how the LM386 is connected to the LM393 op-amps (totally exceeding the absolute maximum ratings for the 393).

Comment: You need to level-shift the signal arriving at U3A's non-inverting input so that it's roughly centered on your 555's output range. A simple voltage-divider between 5V and GND would probably work. C7 is unnecessarily large, but probably not causing (much) trouble.

Comment: I used a voltage divider and connected it in parallel with lm386 output as you suggest but nothing changed

Comment: The LM386 isn’t used in the original circuit that you have just posted <— why have you added it given that most of the problems that I can see are caused by it. Can you justify this change? Can you post layouts?

Comment: Sorry ,  GreatScott added the lm386 at the end of the video but I don't why he didn't add it in his schematic , he adds it because he said the the level of the audio signal was too low and the volume of the speaker was low too. This is the video if you want to see : https://youtu.be/3dQjIeYoIdM

Comment: You can use your PC’s audio input as a poor-man’s oscilloscope. There’s plenty of details online. I’d use a cheap usb sound card in case I did something wrong to nuke the audio input. Since you like to experiment, this would help you get some insight into the problems. You learn the most when things go wrong!

Comment: In addition to what has already been said:  D4 should not exist.  1N4007 (slow) may not a proper substitute for UF4007 (ultra fast) in this circuit, try 1N5819 or 1N4148 instead.  There is also DC bias on the speaker.

Comment: I said to connect the voltage divider to the input of the LM393, not the output of the LM386.